# Free Mindmap software that supports python API

Tags: gratis, python, api, portable, mind-mapping

I need a portable OS-agnostic Mindmap software that supports python API, I want to be able to change the nodes, add text or images programmatically via python.

Answer (score 3):

[XMind](http://www.xmind.net/) is very good and has a python API but it is not platform agnostic other than the Cloud version which is currently only available with the pro-subscription.

However Leo is an **outline based** IDE, Editor, PIM, etc. so not quite what you are looking for.

It is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source.
- Supports python scripts, *(not too surprising given that it is written in python)!*
- Can be installed into and run from a portable installation using [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) by starting the WinPython command prompt and typing: `pip install leo` - *tested*
- Should be able to be run from the USB on Linux & OS-X as it is pure python but it may depend on QT being installed *sorry unable to test.*.