# Mindmapping Python

Tags: python, mind-mapping

Is there any Python software or library I can rely on to :

- Create simple yet nice mindmap
- Export them in Excel (at least csv and then I'll xlwings)

I have discovered [FMEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_mode_and_effects_analysis) for industry is far easier with mind mapping but need to automate the result in excel.
The only reliable language I know is python.

here is the mind map I plan to do
[image]

Here is the excel result I would like
[image]

- Although I can do it through Xmind or mind manager I have then to do a lot of formatting due to the special xls result which is not straight forward from the level of the mind map.
- On the other side the mind map modele is the most convenient to work with a team.

Finally a more complete mind map
[image]

Comment: If you look to the right, you will see a list of possibly related questions. Does [Mindmap software that supports python API](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36803/free-mindmap-software-that-supports-python-api) help?

Comment: Hello, nope I had already checked it but no real good answer. Xmind has a python SDK but I'm looking for something simpler with easier direct access. Ithought python would have a decent project on this point but it seems unfortunately not.

Comment: I do hope that you get your answer, although I must admit that I can't see how a mindmap would be of use in Excel

Comment: Mostly because exposing generic view involving thoughts is more suitable in mindmap and because standard report in the business must  be filled through standard layout in excel.... still looking but I think I will give Xmind a chance

Comment: So, you are looking at using a mindmap to display data? That is a ***very*** interesting concept. I really do hope that you get an answer. I may even code a Python script to generate a mindmap from some of my own data, but that would be very specific to the dataset, and not generic. Maybe if you post some random data (just the structure will do, we don't need the real values) that will help others to see what you want.

Comment: Yes, here I added some pictures of mind map and simplified excel result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yEDGraph Editor is for me the best I would say to create Source -> Target columns and import them into the program. It is free and allows other cool features, like inserting links, images...and different types of layout.

https://www.yworks.com/products/yed/download

There is also a library that allows exporting the networks through python from the extension of this software (.graphml). I didn't research further this library, but it seems useful.

https://github.com/jamesscottbrown/pyyed

Good luck, hope it's helpul.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple text to Freemind conversion program

[A simple text to Freemind conversion program](https://github.com/wbolster/text-to-freemind)

which uses Python libraries.

And may be some programs from the list have Python tools|plugins for generation of mindmaps.

[12 Free Mind Mapping Tools For a Data Scientist To Enhance Structured Thinking](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/06/12-free-mind-mapping-tools-data-scientist-enhance-structured-thinking/)

Comment: @Sylvain did you look into this? Did it meet your needs? If not, how not?

Comment: Awesome recommendation. However, I would like to make a mind map where a subnode from one branch could be connected to another node from another branch. Is this script able to do that?

Comment: @Tian same need as yours. Would like to know whether the subnode could connect to another node from another branch